# What is better way to store temporary data [Memcache or MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I'm using PHP. I want to store temporary data on MySQL. I have also 64GB Memcached server. So, I want use memcache server to store temporary data. But I have a doubt about performace of MySQL and Memcached server.

What is best and speed and reliable way to store get temporary data between MySQL and Memcached ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ha-memcached.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is...it depends.  Memcached is very fast and, even better, you can add multiple machines or shards to your memcached pool more or less invisibly to your application.  MySQL has a variety of storage engines (and potentially replication) which can persist your data if you need to store it.

So it depends on how "temporary" your temp data needs to be. A good way of thinking about it is this: if your server(s) reboot, do you care if the data is there or not?

Data in a memcached shard will be gone if the memcached instance is restarted, but it is often    much faster to access than data in a MySQL table.  Data in MySQL will be more persistent but will be slower to access.

MySQL does have a memory storage engine. Memory storage is fast compared to most other MySQL lookups, and data in it will disappear if the server or service restarts.

If you are choosing between that and Memcached, usually Memcached is the better choice (although it always will depend on your own data - YMMV).  The MySQL memory engine has strict size limits and you will need to prune your data or risk hitting them.  With Memcached, you may hit size limits but the Memcached service will simply start evicting values instead of throwing errors.  Evictions aren't great but at least they won't cause errors you need to handle and you can usually prevent them by watching your metrics and setting appropriate TTLs on your content.